# How to send a queue to a weblogic server using quarkus and apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, weblogic, quarkus

I am using the dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.amqphub.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-qpid-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

my yml properties file

```
quarkus:
   qpid-jms: amqp:url:port
   username: username
   password: password
```

I have a class like

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException;
import javax.jms.Session;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Proccesor;

@ApplicationScoped
public class JMSProducer implements Processor {
    @Inject
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)){
            context.createProducer().send(context.createQueue("my_queue"), exchange.getMessage().getBody(String.class));
        } catch (JMSRuntimeException ex) {}
    }
}
```

After this I call this class as a bean in a procces of my apache camel route.

I'm new to these issues, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Camel and AMQP to produce messages to a queue, then you can use the `camel-quarkus-amqp` extension. It uses `quarkus-qpid-jms`. You can add a dependency for it like this.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then define your connection configuration in `application.yml`.

```yaml
quarkus:
  qpid-jms:
    url: your connection url
    username: your username
    password: your password
```

A simple Camel route to produce a message to a queue might look like this.

```java
public class Routes extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:sendMessage")
                .to("amqp:queue:myQueue");
    }
}
```

Note: to use the `direct` endpoint you need `camel-quarkus-direct` added as a dependency.

There is more information in the Camel & Camel Quarkus documentation:

https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/2.16.x/reference/extensions/amqp.html

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/amqp-component.html